# Why is my fragment not working when im clicking the button for it to switch fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to create two fragments and inserting it into the fragment container while controlling them with two buttons. There was no error it is just that it is not working..... [image]

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

activity_main.xml

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signinButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:onClick="ChangeFragment"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.684"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minikanikoTextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:onClick="ChangeFragment"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signinButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.479"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minikanikoTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.195" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="414dp"
        android:layout_height="516dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signinButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mostly i think the problem is here in the MainActivity

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testonli;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void ChangeFragment(View view){
        Fragment fragment;
        if(view == findViewById(R.id.signinButton)){
            fragment = new SigninFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        if(view == findViewById(R.id.signUpButton)){
            fragment = new SignupFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Put a break point in `ChangeFragment` if nothing is happening my guess is either the method isn't being called as expected, or your if statements never valuate to `true`.

Comment: Hello sir im currently new at android studio.. how do i put break point in ChangeFragment?

Comment: @BigFatBelly click to the right of the line number you want to put a breakpoint on.

Comment: @MauroCurbelo Thankyou for that sir...

Comment: @Jack I already put break point and nothing happens i think the problem is the if statement im really newb at java

Comment: Can you please add XML code

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh I already add the xml code sir i just removed the insignificant code like textView and such..

Comment: @BigFatBelly It looks like everything fine with your code. Make sure you override `onCreateView` and inflate the corresponding layout in the fragment.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh override check

is my inflate correct?

`public class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
`

Comment: @BigFatBelly Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare view's as objects.

i.e. don't

`if(view == findViewById(R.id.signinButton)){`

do

`if(view.getId() == R.id.signinButton){`

This means you are comparing a primitive `int`. with `==` (rather than the `View` object).

When comparing an object (such as `view`) with `==` you are actually comparing if the object reference in memory is the same for the two objects (it won't be).

If you wanted object comparison to work, you would need to use `.equals` i.e. `view.equals(findViewById(R.id.signinButton))` however if that works is determined by the method `equals()` inside the `View.class` so you would go have to check the source code to see if it is going to work. :) TLDR: compare the primitive ints its easier :)

Refs:

https://www.gotoassignmenthelp.com/blog/common-mistakes-java-programmers-commit/ (#7)

https://www.toptal.com/java/top-10-most-common-java-development-mistakes (#10)

Comment: Yes, but here both the references are same, because `findViewById` returns the same reference for single id in the activity.

Comment: when i changed the `if(view == findViewById(R.id.signinButton)){` to `if(view.getId() == R.id.signinButton){` i have to click the signup button for it to work... also the switch part didn't work

Comment: I would also remove `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` & `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias ` from the fragment container